# JPA specification has no effect with CriteriaBuilder.or() method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, specifications

What I want to get is like -

```
SELECT * FROM emials WHERE user_id = ?1 AND (`to` like '%?2%' OR `from` LIKE '%?2%' OR subject LIKE '%?2%');
```

To get such I have following specification like -

```
public class VendorEmailSpecification {
    public static Specification<VendorEmail> filter(String filterText) {
        return new Specification<VendorEmail>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<VendorEmail> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();

                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(filterText)) {
                    /***
                    * this block donot have any effects
                    **/
                    predicate = criteriaBuilder.or(
                            criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("to"),"%"+ filterText +"%")),
                            criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("from"),"%"+ filterText +"%")),
                            criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("subject"),"%"+ filterText +"%")),
                            criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("message"),"%"+ filterText +"%"))
                   );
                }
                // there is an relation of ManyToOne with user and AuthUserThread.getContext() gives an object of User entity.
                // this working perfectly
                predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate,criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("user"), AuthUserThread.getContext()));


                return predicate;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What mistake is there and how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem in another way -

```
public class VendorEmailSpecification {
    public static Specification<VendorEmail> filter(String filterText) {
        return new Specification<VendorEmail>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<VendorEmail> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
                predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("user"), AuthUserThread.getContext());
                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(filterText)) {
                    Predicate toPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("to"), "%"+filterText+"%");
                    Predicate fromPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("from"), "%"+filterText+"%");
                    Predicate subjectPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("subject"), "%"+filterText+"%");
                    Predicate messagePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("message"), "%"+filterText+"%");
                    Predicate orPredicate = criteriaBuilder.or(toPredicate, fromPredicate, subjectPredicate, messagePredicate);
                    predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, orPredicate);
                    return predicate;
                }

                predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate);
                return predicate;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. The multiple instances of Predicate is much better. It makes the code easier to read and understand. But, you accidentally left a dinosaur bone that originated in my code on line 4:  `String filterValue = filterText`. You may want to remove that line. Actually, I'm just going to delete my answer - it's just clutter at this point.

Comment: @SeanMickey Thank you sir. I just deleted that line of code.

Comment: does this make sense if next line is overriding value? `Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `filterText` parameter will have gone out of scope when the `toPredicate()` method is called.

If you add a member to the anonymous `Specification<VendorEmail>` instance returned by the `filter()` method, assign the value of the `filterText` parameter to the member, and update the remaining code to refer to the new member, as shown below, that should resolve the problem:

```
public class VendorEmailSpecification {
    public static Specification<VendorEmail> filter(String filterText) {
        return new Specification<VendorEmail>() {
            private String filterValue = filterText;

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<VendorEmail> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.filterValue)) {
                    /***
                    * this block donot have any effects
                    **/
                    predicate = criteriaBuilder.or(
                        criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("to"),"%"+ this.filterValue +"%")),
                        criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("from"),"%"+ this.filterValue +"%")),
                        criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("subject"),"%"+ this.filterValue +"%")),
                        criteriaBuilder.or(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("message"),"%"+ this.filterValue +"%"))
               );
            }
            // there is an relation of ManyToOne with user and AuthUserThread.getContext() gives an object of User entity.
            // this working perfectly
            predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate,criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("user"), AuthUserThread.getContext()));
            return predicate;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyway thank you sir. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Is the code within the if statement that checks `filterText` running?